# Is there any way of changing the layout of view in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

How to override the layout used by the controller to render view which is in third party module?

Answer (score 1):

@msushil Never accepted an answer, so I am probably wasting my time here.. I am posting this because it might help someone else in the future, as I highly doubt the OP will ever select an answer for this question...

You can change the layout from within your view. In Yii2, you reference your controller by `$this->context`. So you can change the layout like this:

```
$this->context->layout = 'new-layout';
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the relative action:

```
public function actionYourAction($id)
{
    $this->layout = 'yourNewLayout';

    return $this->render('yourView', ['model' =>$model]);
}
```